# How to Import csv file to database in Typo3 extbase backend extention

Tags: typo3, extbase, import-csv

I created an extention using extention builder product model

```
CREATE TABLE tx_product_domain_model_product (

    name varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    no int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    description text,

);
```

I need import the data using csv file in Typo3 backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing CSV files can be complicated if one file includes a table where data shall be written in different database-tables but keeping the connection.

Nevertheless there exists an extension for simple and complicated CSV imports, it's `external_import` and can be found [here](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/external_import/).
A tutorial for `external_import` can be installed as [separated extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/externalimport_tut/).